# JQuery $.each() - struggling to get key value pairs of object

Tags: jquery, loops, object, each, associative-array

I have the following Object:

```
var business_challenges =[{title: 'Business Challenges'}, [{digital_trans: 'Digital Transformation'}, {agile_mobile:'Agile & Mobile Working always_on'},  {always_on:'Always on Infrastructure'}, {connect_protect: 'Connect & Protect'}, {cost_cutting:'Cost Cutting/Maximise Investment'}, {improving_cust: 'Improving Customer Engagement'} ]];
var business_divisions = [{title: 'Business Divisions'},[{SMB:'SMB'}, {DCS:'DCS'}, {DPS:'DPS'}]];
var filters = $.merge(business_divisions, business_challenges);
```

I am trying to loop through the object to get the key:value pairs but am struggling.  The Key value is numeric instead of the associative array key and the value is an object.  I have tried nesting another $each but this doesn't work.

Can anyone assist?  Do I need to change how the **filters** object is put together?

```
var filter_html = '<ul>';
        //var filtersJSON = $.parseJSON(filters);
        $.each(filters, function(i, data) {
            var filter_title = data.title;  //THIS WORKS

            filter_html = filter_html+filter_title;
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                filter_html = filter_html+'<li><input type="checkbox" value="'+ key +'">'+ val.key +'</li>';  //THIS DOESNT WORK

            });

        });
        filter_html = filter_html+ '</ul>';


        $('#filterControls').html(filter_html);
```

Comment: That data structure is very strange. Do you control it's source?

Comment: yes, I can change it if needs be.  Its the first time Ive tried to put together an associative array / object in Javascript.  Im more used to PHP so am a little confused!

Comment: I think you should use `$.extend()` i.p.o. $.merge().

Comment: Well your current issue is you need another nested loop to iterate sub array in each one and a merge or extend is going to complicate things even more

Comment: Suggest you go back to the source and structure this in more consistent way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to

> get the key:value pairs 
>   you may test each element in your each loop.

Indeed, the object filters  contains objects and array of objects.

For array elements you can get the current object value with:

```
var key = Object.keys(val)[0];  // get the key name
var value = val[key];   // from the key name you can get the value
```

This because each object inside arrays has a different property name.

The snippet:

```js
var business_challenges = [{title: 'Business Challenges'}, [{digital_trans: 'Digital Transformation'}, {agile_mobile: 'Agile & Mobile Working always_on'}, {always_on: 'Always on Infrastructure'}, {connect_protect: 'Connect & Protect'}, {cost_cutting: 'Cost Cutting/Maximise Investment'}, {improving_cust: 'Improving Customer Engagement'}]];
var business_divisions = [{title: 'Business Divisions'}, [{SMB: 'SMB'}, {DCS: 'DCS'}, {DPS: 'DPS'}]];
var filters = $.merge(business_divisions, business_challenges);
var filter_html = '<ul>';
$.each(filters, function (i, data) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Array]') {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
      var key = Object.keys(val)[0];
      var value = val[key];
      filter_html = filter_html + '<li><input type="checkbox" value="' + key + '">' + value + '</li>';
      console.log('Object N. ' + key + ': ' + JSON.stringify(val));
    });
  } else {
    filter_html = filter_html + data.title;
  }

});
filter_html = filter_html + '</ul>';


$('#filterControls').html(filter_html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="filterControls"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try `$.each(myObject, function(keyName, keyValue)`

```js
var myObject = {
  string: 'someText',
  number: 123321,
  array: [1, 2, 3, 4]
};

$.each(myObject, function(keyName, keyValue) {
  console.log(keyName + ': ' + keyValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```